# Ruby on Rails variable session nill on change controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm new in Ruby on Rails.

When I put data in a variable session (session[:user_id]) and redirect to other page the next controller doesn't see the session. It returns session={}.

```
user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        redirect_to pages_url, notice: "Hello"
    end
```

I saw that application is telling me a warning:

```
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

Looking in internet I found that session variable will be deleted if csrf token authenticity is not ok.

I run on shell "rake secret", and copy and paste in config/initializers/secret_token.rb:

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Your secret key for verifying the integrity of signed cookies.
# If you change this key, all old signed cookies will become invalid!
# Make sure the secret is at least 30 characters and all random,
# no regular words or you'll be exposed to dictionary attacks.
myApp::Application.config.secret_token = '4a5c2aabe7610666ac793d425ece06f24c87747a38d14991b4f352780e55b17e9bcee977c1579eec99e1d30f506671903ab87601346f0e96102a187df2aff1e6'
```

Also I have this in config/initializers/session_store.rb

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

myApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_myApp_session', :domain => :all

# Use the database for sessions instead of the cookie-based default,
# which shouldn't be used to store highly confidential information
# (create the session table with "rails generate session_migration")
# myApp::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store
```

Maybe I have bad configured the secret_token? Maybe I can access to session variable in other way?

Comment: Sorry for that comment but it's really an option: have you restarted your server after the changes?

Comment: Yes, I restarted the server many times.